# How do I create a transparent button in Java Script (Smartface)

Tags: javascript, button, uibutton, transparent, smartface.io

I am just trying to make a transparent button in the smartface cloud IDE using java script, and every time I make it transparent it wont read a click. I can increase the opacity all the way to alpha = .1 but when I set it equal to zero it wont work. How can I fix this, or is there another way to do this. I just want the button to take this form...

left : "50%",
top : "50%",
height : "50%",
width : "50%",
(The bottom right hand corner)

This is the code I have for the button (It doesn't work)

```
var myTextBtn = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
    left : '50%',
    top : '50%',
    width : '50%',
    height : '50%',
    text : "",
    onPressed : alert("Pressed"),
});
myTextBtn.alpha = 0;
page1.add(myTextBtn);
```

Comment: Can´t you put alpha in a really low value such as 0.0001?

Comment: No that doesn't work either, lol I wish it did though!

Comment: Not sure then, have´t really used smartface

Answer (score 1):

`alpha` shouldn't affect click unless it is `0`. The problem is `onPressed` accepts callback function. But you are calling `alert` function there and giving its result to `onPressed` property.

**Try this:**

```
var myTextBtn = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
    left : '50%',
    top : '50%',
    width : '50%',
    height : '50%',
    text : "",
    onPressed : function() {
        alert("Pressed");
    }
});
myTextBtn.alpha = 0.5;
page1.add(myTextBtn);
```

Comment: I need it to be completely invisible to see how it effects the background. and I tried to when someone clicks the screen it reads an x y coordinate and see if it fits a certain condition but it is to slow(as in it cant handle a lot of touches in a short period of time.

Comment: If you want to handle touches you can use `onTouch` event if it works on TextButton. Did you try that event?

Comment: Yes I did but there is a larger lag between readings. I doesn't pick up quick clicks.